# How To map a network Drive through preferences by using wmi query in server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I want to map a network drive through preferences option. For this mapping i want to go with wmi query, which is in item level targeting, I done with all the initial work like giving its path, drive letter etc. Now i gone to common tab and selected item level targeting. In which i selected wmi query and i wrote the query as

```
select username from win32_ComputerSystem where domain="www.test.com".
```

I am running windows server 2008, my domain is www.test.com and i am using windows 7 machine as client of my server. After applying the preferences i ran gpupdate /force also on client an then log off and log on but i am not getting the network drive on my client. Did I wrote the wmi query wrong or anything else?

Comment: It's usually best to check the preview before posting your question. At first I was going to say that we couldn't tell you if your query was correct since it wasn't in your question. Then I spotted it in amongst the wall of text.